# Replace the values of some keys in a single line text file

Tags: text-processing

I have a large file called `res.dat` that contains certain data I need modified. All data is on one single line.

For example:

```
L1TRAIN="200" NEEDL2="14" L2TRAIN="300" NEEDL3="16" L3TRAIN="400" NEEDL4="99" L4TRAIN="600" NEEDL5="99" L5TRAIN="900" DELAY="60" COOLTIME="0" KORNAME="화염풍" SKILLTYPE="0" TOOLTIP="A defensive spell that allows you to push away enemies of lower level. This spell has a fixed chance for success. The range of the spell and chance of success increase with training." /><VALUE MAGID="9" MAGNAME="Lavastrike" TYPE="0" EFFECTTYPE="5" EFFECT="7" SPELL="11" POWER="14" MAXPOWER="18" DEFSPELL="15" DEFPOWER="12" DEFMAXPOWER="16" JOB="1" PHASE="0" NEEDL1="20" L1TRAIN="500" NEEDL2="22" L2TRAIN="600" NEEDL3="24" L3TRAIN="700" NEEDL4="99" L4TRAIN="900" NEEDL5="99" L5TRAIN="1200" DELAY="80" COOLTIME="0" KORNAME="염사장" SKILLTYPE="0" TOOLTIP="A spell that shoots out line of fire along the ground, damaging all enemies caught within the fire. Its damage increases with training." /><VALUE MAGID="10" MAGNAME="LightningBeam" TYPE="2" EFFECTTYPE="6" EFFECT="8" SPELL="12" POWER="14" MAXPOWER="14" DEFSPELL="15" DEFPOWER="12" DEFMAXPOWER="16" JOB="1" PHASE="0" NEEDL1="21" L1TRAIN="500" NEEDL2="23" L2TRAIN="600" NEEDL3="25" L3TRAIN="700" NEEDL4="99" L4TRAIN="900" NEEDL5="99" L5TRAIN="1200" DELAY="80" COOLTIME="0" KORNAME="뢰인장" SKILLTYPE="0"
```

I need to run a script that looks for the data inside the double quotes of `L1TRAIN`, `L2TRAIN`, `L3TRAIN`, `L4TRAIN` and `L5TRAIN` and update all of them to  `L1TRAIN="100" L2TRAIN="200" L3TRAIN="300" L4TRAIN="400" L5TRAIN="500"` There is loads that need modifying, all the data is on one line.

The output of the example should be:

```
L1TRAIN="100" NEEDL2="14" L2TRAIN="200" NEEDL3="16" L3TRAIN="300" NEEDL4="99" L4TRAIN="400" NEEDL5="99" L5TRAIN="500" DELAY="60" COOLTIME="0" KORNAME="화염풍" SKILLTYPE="0" TOOLTIP="A defensive spell that allows you to push away enemies of lower level. This spell has a fixed chance for success. The range of the spell and chance of success increase with training." /><VALUE MAGID="9" MAGNAME="Lavastrike" TYPE="0" EFFECTTYPE="5" EFFECT="7" SPELL="11" POWER="14" MAXPOWER="18" DEFSPELL="15" DEFPOWER="12" DEFMAXPOWER="16" JOB="1" PHASE="0" NEEDL1="20" L1TRAIN="100" NEEDL2="22" L2TRAIN="200" NEEDL3="24" L3TRAIN="300" NEEDL4="99" L4TRAIN="400" NEEDL5="99" L5TRAIN="500" DELAY="80" COOLTIME="0" KORNAME="염사장" SKILLTYPE="0" TOOLTIP="A spell that shoots out line of fire along the ground, damaging all enemies caught within the fire. Its damage increases with training." /><VALUE MAGID="10" MAGNAME="LightningBeam" TYPE="2" EFFECTTYPE="6" EFFECT="8" SPELL="12" POWER="14" MAXPOWER="14" DEFSPELL="15" DEFPOWER="12" DEFMAXPOWER="16" JOB="1" PHASE="0" NEEDL1="21" L1TRAIN="100" NEEDL2="23" L2TRAIN="200" NEEDL3="25" L3TRAIN="300" NEEDL4="99" L4TRAIN="400" NEEDL5="99" L5TRAIN="500" DELAY="80" COOLTIME="0" KORNAME="뢰인장" SKILLTYPE="0"
```

Comment: Yes double quotes. I don't have the coding ability, still learning

Comment: No spaces or letters, only numbers. Yes it's in one large file called "res.dat"

Comment: No it's all in one line. I have added a better example.

Comment: I am not sure what I am missing sorry. Whatever is inside the "L1Train",2,3,4,5 needs to be changed to 100,200,300,400,500

Comment: Yes many replications that are different L1TRAIN="" for example one is L1TRAIN="100" another might be L1TRAIN="500", L1TRAIN="2000" and so on. They all need to be L1TRAIN="100"

Comment: Are you stuck with this format, or could you use `json`? `{L1TRAIN:"200", NEEDL2:"14", L2TRAIN:"300" …}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it with `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(L\([1-5]\)TRAIN="\)[^"]*/\1\200/g' res.dat
```

this uses grouping and back-referencing, replacing any occurrence of

```
LnTRAIN="anything_except_double_quote
```

with

```
LnTRAIN="n00
```

where *n* is a number between `1` and `5`.